# C++ random srand code-if else does not give correct result

Tags: c++

I am not receiving correct response to my code. It should give 'Excellent' when I type in correct number; however, it always outputs 'Incorrect' - Please suggest.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int guess()
{
    int x = 0;
    x = 1 + rand() % 1000;
    return x;
}

int main()
{
    int input = 0;
    srand( time( 0 ) );
    cout << guess() << endl;
    cout << "I have a number between 1 and 1000. " << endl;
    cout << "Can you guess my number? " << endl;
    cout << "Please type your first guess. " << endl;
    cin >> input;

    if (guess() == input)
        cout << "Excellent! You guessed the number! " << endl;
    else
        cout << "Incorrect! " << endl;

    system ("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but get in the habit of initializing objects with meaningful values, rather than initializing and immediately overwriting that initialization. In this case, that means changing `int x = 0; x = 1 + rand() % 1000;` to `int x = 1 + rand() % 1000;`. (Personally, I would even use a variable here: `return 1 + rand() % 1000;`, but that's more of a style thing)

Comment: Years ago now I had the pleasure of stumbling across a strange rule in a coding standard: No arithmetic in a return statement. Turns out a few years earlier one of the programmers found a bug in the compiler that cranked out hilariously wrong assembly for 64 bit math in a return statement. The compiler vender wasn't interested in fixing the bug, but they did fix it in the next version, and the dev team couldn't just dump the compiler and use a different one, so an administrative fix got bolted onto code reviews. To this day I rarely do anything significant in a return statement out of habit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are calling twice the function `guess()`, so it will give you probably different values at each run. You must store the value and then compare it with the original one.